# Remove duplicate words (case-insensitive)

Tags: php, duplicates

```
$text = "Wyse Dell WYSE";

$words = array_unique(explode(' ',$text));
$words = implode(' ',$words);

echo $words;

// output: Wyse dell WYSE
```

This solution works case-sensitive and immediately repeating words, but not always as in the example above.  I need it to do a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Are you trying to remove case sensitivity from this? I'm a little unsure what your question is.

Comment: Yes, correct, I need case-insensitive removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = "Wyse Dell WYSE";

$words = array_iunique(explode(' ',$text));
$words = implode(' ',$words);

echo $words;



function array_iunique($array) {
    return array_intersect_key(
        $array,
        array_unique(array_map("StrToLower",$array))
    );
}
```

source: [case-insensitive array_unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276349/case-insensitive-array-unique/2276400#2276400)

1. `array_map` applies `strtolower` to all values and returns an array with all values lower cased,
2. `array_unique` removes all duplicates from return of `array_map`
3. `array_intersect_key` returns an array containing all the entries of $array which have keys that are present in return of `array_unique`
4. This will prevent only first existence of word and remove others

More details about functions:

`array_map`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

`array_intersect_key`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

`strtolower`: http://php.net/strtolower

Comment: Maybe you also want to explain what your function does

Comment: @Rizier123 Which in turn seems to come from a comment in the php manual. And none with a nice explanation of what it does exactly :-(

Comment: @jeroen I know! That's why I want here a nice explanation (It's also almost a dupe from my perspective)

Comment: Obviously if he copied it he doesn't have an explanation, which makes the answer near irrelevant.

Comment: @EternalHour I can't explain more than this, looking at php manual will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$text = "Wyse Dell WYSE";

$words = array_unique(explode(' ',strtolower($text)));
$words = implode(' ',$words);

echo $words;
```

Comment: Thanks but it changes everything to lowercase which is not desired. :(