# PHP array unique values despite of upper/lowercase

Tags: php, arrays

I am want to remove duplicated value from array so i am doing this

```
$input = array("APPL", "berry", "apple", "berry");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

So it will output:

> APPLE,apple,berry

I want to get result like output apple only once despite of lowercase and uppercase, how can i do this? is there any function in PHP like "array_unique" which i have to use instead, in situation like this? *(without making all characters upper or lowercase)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [case-insensitive array\_unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276349/case-insensitive-array-unique)

Comment: [case-insensitive array_unique][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276349/case-insensitive-array-unique

Comment: First of all, I assume you meant to write `$input = array("APPLE", "berry", "apple", "berry");`. Secondly, if you are looking for a result of `['APPLE', 'apple', 'berry']` you are doing a case-sensitive filter, not case-insensitive. In which case, just use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: @Darragh how do i make it case-insensitive? i don't want to change all of them in upper or lowercase.

Comment: I have post my answer check it and let me know

Comment: @GiorgiKhmaladze - the output example you mentioned (`APPLE,apple,berry`) doesn't seem to match what you are asking. Did you mean you want (`apple,berry`) as the output?

Comment: @Deena ty thats what i was looking for

Comment: @Darragh yes i know i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php
$input = array("APPLE", "berry", "apple", "berry");

$data = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $input)));

print_r($data);
?>
```

https://eval.in/416659

Answer (score 0):

An array is case sensitive.
No function to ignore it while printing, but you may change the case before.
Try this :

```
$input = array("APPLE", "berry", "apple", "berry");
$lower_input = array_map('strtolower', $input);
$result2 = array_unique($lower_input);
print_r($result2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
function array_iunique($array) {
        return array_intersect_key(
            $array,
            array_unique(array_map("StrToLower",$array))
        );
    }
```