# PHP - array_unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code which gets the data from various columns in the same table subject to criteria defined.

```
$arraySecondaryNames =  array();

$sqlQuerySecondaryCat01 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT secondary_category_set_1 FROM table_name WHERE primary_category_set_1 = :primary_cat");
$sqlQuerySecondaryCat01->execute(array(':primary_cat'=>$primaryCatText, ':profile_switch'=>$profileSwitchOn, ':profile_visibility'=>$profileVisShow));
foreach($sqlQuerySecondaryCat01 as $sqlResultSecondaryCat01){
    $arraySecondaryNames[] = $sqlResultSecondaryCat01['secondary_category_set_1'];
}

$sqlQuerySecondaryCat02 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT secondary_category_set_2 FROM table_name WHERE primary_category_set_2 = :primary_cat");
$sqlQuerySecondaryCat02->execute(array(':primary_cat'=>$primaryCatText, ':profile_switch'=>$profileSwitchOn, ':profile_visibility'=>$profileVisShow));
foreach($sqlQuerySecondaryCat02 as $sqlResultSecondaryCat02){
    $arraySecondaryNames[] = $sqlResultSecondaryCat02['secondary_category_set_2'];
}
```

The output is sometimes is duplicate: therefore I use the following

```
$arraySecondaryCatNames = array_filter($arraySecondaryCatNames);
$arraySecondaryCatNames = array_unique($arraySecondaryCatNames);
```

The output still contains duplicates:

```
Array ( [0] => Bride and Groom [1] => Bride and Groom [2] => Bride and Groom )
```

I'm not sure how to eliminate the duplicates. The values are for [0],[1] and [3] - are identical since array_unique uses case sensitive.

How do I eliminate duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276349/case-insensitive-array-unique

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
     $arraySecondaryNames =  array();
     $arraySecondaryNames1 = array();
     $arraySecondaryNames2 = array();

        $sqlQuerySecondaryCat01 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT secondary_category_set_1 FROM table_name WHERE primary_category_set_1 = :primary_cat");
        $sqlQuerySecondaryCat01->execute(array(':primary_cat'=>$primaryCatText, ':profile_switch'=>$profileSwitchOn, ':profile_visibility'=>$profileVisShow));
        foreach($sqlQuerySecondaryCat01 as $sqlResultSecondaryCat01){
            $arraySecondaryNames1[] = $sqlResultSecondaryCat01['secondary_category_set_1']; // First array
        }

        $sqlQuerySecondaryCat02 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT secondary_category_set_2 FROM table_name WHERE primary_category_set_2 = :primary_cat");
        $sqlQuerySecondaryCat02->execute(array(':primary_cat'=>$primaryCatText, ':profile_switch'=>$profileSwitchOn, ':profile_visibility'=>$profileVisShow));
        foreach($sqlQuerySecondaryCat02 as $sqlResultSecondaryCat02){
            $arraySecondaryNames2[] = $sqlResultSecondaryCat02['secondary_category_set_2']; //Second array
        }



        $arraySecondaryCatNames = array_unique( array_merge($arraySecondaryNames1,$arraySecondaryNames2) );
       //Merged array with no duplicate values     
       print_r($arraySecondaryCatNames);
```

Comment: Hi, it gives the same output it gave to me. The duplicate values are not eliminated

Comment: I used your code but replaced array_unique with just array:$arraySecondaryCatNames = array($arraySecondaryNames01,$arraySecondaryNames02,$arraySecondaryNames03, $arrayPremiumSecondaryNames01, $arrayPremiumSecondaryNames02, $arrayPremiumSecondaryNames03);
$arraySecondaryCatNames = array_unique($arraySecondaryCatNames);

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arraySecondaryCatNames_filter = $arraySecondaryCatNames_unique = array();
$arraySecondaryCatNames_filter = array_filter($arraySecondaryCatNames);
$arraySecondaryCatNames_unique =  array_unique($arraySecondaryCatNames_filter);
print_r($arraySecondaryCatNames_unique);
```

Comment: Can you explain this please? `$arraySecondaryCatNames_filter = $arraySecondaryCatNames_unique = array();`

Comment: I just take different variables and initialized those array with blank array.